# A change in a countable set of points does not affect the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

I know that a change in a finite number of points of an integrable function does not change the integral (Riemann integral). Recently I started to learn about Fourier transform, and in my book they define the norm $ L^2 $.

In order for $L^2$ to be a norm, we need to define an equivalence relation, and the relation is defined as the following:

If $f$, $g$ are functions such that $f(x)=g(x)$ **almost for any $ x \in \mathbb{R}$** then we say that $f$ is equivalent to $g$. Where "almost everywhere" means that the set of points of which $ f(x) \neq g(x) $ is of measure zero.

As I understood, if 2 functions are equal up to a set of points of measure zero, then the integrals of the function would remain the same.

For a finite number of points I can totally understand. But even for a countably many points I cant see how this is true. For example, if we take the 0 function in the segment $ [0,1] $ and change the rational points to be $ 1 $, we get Dirichlet's function which is not integrable.

So where is this all come from? And what is the right claim?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is using the Lebesgue integral. Otherwise, you are correct that changing a countable number of values of a function could turn a Riemann integrable function into one which is not Riemann integrable.

It is a theorem that whenever the (proper) Riemann integral of a function exists, it equals the Lebesgue integral. So changing a countable number of function values will result in the same Riemann integral, provided the Riemann integral exists in both cases.

For improper integrals, if the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals both exist, they are equal. But it may be that both don't exist - consider the integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ over $(0, \infty)$ for example, where the Riemann improper integral exists but the Lebesgue integral is undefined.